# Why does OpenERP report query result vary from SQL query result?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Here is my Python code:

```
class sign_in_out_model_class(osv.osv):
    _name = "sign.in.out"
    _description = "Sign In / Out Report" 
    _auto = False
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Emp No', size=128, readonly=True,select=True),
        'reldate':fields.char('Date', readonly=True,select=True),
        'sign_in': fields.char('Sign In', readonly=True,select=True),
        'sign_out': fields.char('Sign Out', readonly=True,select=True),
    }
    _order = 'sign_in asc'

    def init(self, cr):
        tools.sql.drop_view_if_exists(cr, 'sign_in_out')
        cr.execute("""CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW sign_in_out AS (
                        select max(dup_id) as id,name,
to_char(min(date),'YY/MM/DD') as reldate,
to_char(min(date),'HH12:MIam') as sign_in,
to_char(max(date),'HH12:MIam') as sign_out 
from text_based_attendance 
group by date(date),name)""")

sign_in_out_model_class()
```

Which gives below output

[image: result in openerp]

but when I run that query in pgAdmin it gives below result

[image: pgAdmin result]

I need to know what the reason is for this difference?
Any issue with my coding?

Comment: you can see in image 1 this is sorted by id by default odoo _order by ids that's why the order is change.

Answer (score 0):

The Cursor class is defined by `psycopg2` and extended by the Odoo framework. That means you might think you execute raw queries using `cr.execute` but you are not.

Check the `sql_db.py` file for the class `Cursor` and read the documentation there. Basically the cr object is an instance of this class, and this class basically wraps the Cursor of `psycopg2` altering functionality. Check the `execute` method there and you will see that it does not directly call the `execute` method of psycopg rather it does some processing first. Try printing the `params` there to see which parameters are passed in the end.

**In the end even if you are using raw sql you are still using Odoo's ORM, that means additional parameters/restrictions are in place.**

For example, on pgadmin you (possibly) have unrestricted access to data, but using the Cursor you have the same access rights as the user in `self.env.uid`.

Also, check the [documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html) because the cache might be a reason your see different results.